# Passing data maps with normal functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date input with a button, such that changing the date input and pressing the button shows a new schedule with updated dates. I'd like to get rid of the button entirely and just make it so that changing the date renders a new schedule.

My function to render a schedule `scheduleFunc` has to take a data map. So far all my attempts to pass one or simulate a click haven't worked properly. Anyone have any pointers on how to write this? Here's the current code with the working click:

```
scheduleFunc(el) {

    // do lots of schedule rendering

    $("#jumpDate").change(function(){
          newStart = Date.parse($("#jumpDate").val())
          newStartPass = Math.round(newStart / 1000)
          newEndPass = newStartPass + 604800;
          if (newStartPass > new Date() / 1000) {
            $("#jumpButton").click({startTime:newStartPass, endTime:newEndPass}, scheduleFunc);    
          }
    });

    //do more stuff

}
```

Comment: why con't you call the functions that would get called by the click event in the change handler? I'm not certain I understand why you still need to trigger the click. If the actions in the click event handler are not in a function just place them in one and call that with the parameters you are trying to pass.

Comment: just call `scheduleFunc` directly and pass in appropriate arguments.

Comment: Functions handle data maps differently than variables passed normally in a function. In this case, within `scheduleFunc` I have to get the passed information by doing `el.data.startTime`. This is important because of how `scheduleFunc` is originally generated, so I have to mirror the way the information is passed here.

Comment: So is that function already bound to the click handler for the button? Show all relevant code

Comment: you could format your data object to match the expectations of scheduleFun. `{data:{startTime:newStartPass, endTime:newEndPass}}`. Unless it explicitly requires an element in which case you can use `document.createElement("div")` and add the appropriate data values that way and then pass that to the `scheduleFunc`.

Comment: @scrappedcola yup, that did the trick. Can't believe it was so simple. If you write it up as an answer, I'll give you credit for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your data object to match the expectations of the `scheduleFun`. `{data:{startTime:newStartPass, endTime:newEndPass}}`

Alternatively if it explicitly requires an element in which case you can use `document.createElement("div")`, add the appropriate data values that way, and then pass that new element to the `scheduleFunc`